# PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($target_file) is working on localhost but not on server

Tags: php, jquery, excel

**While importing excel file on to server it will not work or not give any Error.**

Here, exactly what happened is, First at the time of importing excel file first i am uploading that file to server then i am using that file to import that data into database.
File is correctly uploaded to server, but then it will not further work.
I have debug that file and get to know that

```
PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($target_file); is not working
```

Please help.Thanks

Code is here:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function closeWin() {
            myWindow.close();
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <?php
    session_start();

    function GetFileExtension($imagetype) {
        if (empty($imagetype))
            return false;
        switch ($imagetype) {
            case 'xlsx': return '.xlsx';
            case 'xls': return '.xls';
            default: return false;
        }
    }

    libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
//include the following 2 files
    include './config.php';
    require '../../PHPExcel_1.8.0/Classes/PHPExcel.php';
    require_once '../../PHPExcel_1.8.0/Classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';
    $target_dir = './uploads/';
    $product = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'product');
    $username = $_SESSION['pman'];
    $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["userfile"]["name"]);
    $filename = basename($_FILES["userfile"]["name"]);
    $file_type = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    $Type_status = true;
    $ext = GetFileExtension($file_type);
    if ($ext == FALSE) {
        echo 'This File Type is not Supported';
        echo 'Please use Excel sheets with extension *.xlsx or *.xls';
        echo '<a id="click" href="javascript:window.close()">Close this     window</a>';
    } else {
        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["userfile"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
            echo 'File Uploaded';
        } else {
            echo 'error'.  mysql_error();
        }
        $objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($target_file);
        foreach ($objPHPExcel->getWorksheetIterator() as $worksheet) {
            $worksheetTitle = $worksheet->getTitle();
            $highestRow = $worksheet->getHighestRow(); // e.g. 10
            $highestColumn = $worksheet->getHighestColumn(); // e.g 'F'
            if ($highestColumn != 'L') {
                echo 'This File is as per given Standered';
                echo 'Please Check Template for perticular standards';
                echo '<a id="click"   href="javascript:window.close()">Close this window</a>';
                break;
            }
            $highestColumnIndex = PHPExcel_Cell::columnIndexFromString($highestColumn);
            $nrColumns = ord($highestColumn) - 64;
            echo "<br>The worksheet " . $worksheetTitle . " has ";
            echo $nrColumns . ' columns (A-' . $highestColumn . ') ';
            echo ' and ' . $highestRow . ' row.';
            echo '<a id="click" href="javascript:window.close()">Close this window</a>';
            echo '<br>Data: <table border="1"><tr>';
            for ($row = 1; $row <= $highestRow; ++$row) {
                $valarray = array();
                echo '<tr>';
                for ($col = 0; $col < $highestColumnIndex; ++$col) {
                    $cell = $worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow($col, $row);
                    $valarray[] = $cell->getValue();
                    $dataType = PHPExcel_Cell_DataType::dataTypeForValue($valarray[$col]);
                    echo '<td>' . $valarray[$col] . '</td>';
                }
                if ($row > 1) 
                {
                    if (strtolower($valarray[2]) == 'prepaid' || strtolower($valarray[2]) == 'postpaid') {
                        if ($valarray[0] == "") {
                            $Type_status = false;
                        } else {

                        }
                    } else {
                        $Type_status = false;
                    }
                }

                echo '</tr>';
            }
            echo '</table>';
        }
        $count = 0;
        if ($Type_status == true) {
            if ($highestColumn != 'L') {

            } else {
                $upd = null;
                $cmt = null;
                $rev = 'Pending';
                for ($row = 2; $row <= $highestRow; ++$row) {
                    $val = array();
                    for ($col = 0; $col < $highestColumnIndex; ++$col) {
                        $cell = $worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow($col, $row);
                        $val[] = $cell->getValue();

                    }
                    $testcaseid = '1234' . rand(50, 5000);

                    $sql_insert = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO tmtool.testcase_master (`Testcase_id`,`Testcase_title`, `Precondition`, `Product_id`, `Subscriber_type`, `Created_by`, `Activation_mode`, `Testcase_desc`, `Date_created`, `Test_step`, `Expected_result`, `Category`, `Sub_category`,`Language`,`Priority`, `Updated_date`, `Comment`, `Review`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
                    $sql_insert->bind_param('ssssssssssssssssss', $testcaseid, $val[0], $val[1], $product, $val[2], $username, $val[3], $val[4], $val[5], $val[6], $val[7], $val[8], $val[9], $val[10], $val[11], $upd, $cmt, $rev);
                    if ($sql_insert->execute()) {
                        $sql_insert->close();
                        $count++;
                    } else {
                        die(mysqli_error($conn));
                    }

                }
                echo $count . 'Test cases has been Imported to the Database';
                echo '<a id="click" href="javascript:window.close()">Close this window</a>';
            }
        } else {
            echo 'Some Testcase dont have Subscriber Type or Testcase Title ...It is a Mandatory Field. Can not be Empty';
            echo '<a id="click" href="javascript:window.close()">Close this window</a>';
        }
    }
    ?>
</body>
```

Comment: So does `PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($target_file);` throw any exceptions? What type of file does PHPExcel identify it as? What Reader is PHPExcel using to load the file? You have the file, you can see what it contains.... we can't see it, so we can't know what is happening

Comment: PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($target_file) Is not throwing any exception. PhP excel is use .xls or .xlsx file

Comment: What Writer does a call to `PHPExcel_IOFactory::identify()` return? The file extension is meaningless. And is anything written to PHP or webserver logs?

Comment: it will return excel2007 and string(9) but in localhost.It will not return anything on server

Comment: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'PHPExcel_Reader_Exception' with message 'Could not open  for reading! File does not exist.' in /opt/lampp/htdocs/tmtool/PHPExcel_1.8.0/Classes/PHPExcel/Reader/Excel2007.php:82 And some warning for session_start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the problem.Problem is with my library.I have used phpexcel library version 1.8.0. but still there is some update occurs after words.

What i have used in past is not working with .xlsx file properly.but can work with .xls.

Problem i have encounter is: when i uploads .xlsx file it will automatically convert that into .xls. And not able to handle.
Solution: I have update my PHPExcel library so its work fine for both .xlsx and .xls.

Answer (score 0):

It could be an issue with the file size . Maybe PHPExcel is unable to read your file if it is huge. This is a good place to clear your doubts: https://phpexcel.codeplex.com/workitem/list/basic

Comment: size of the file is only 12 kb which i have tried, still it is not working

Comment: Are you sure you're path is correct ..have you changed the path for the server